# How can I write an mltable artifact from python to a local folder?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk

I am using the mltable library on an AzureML notebook.

I can successufully load a local csv file as an mltable:

```
from mltable import from_delimited_files
paths = [{'file': "dati_estra_test.csv"}]
dati = from_delimited_files(paths)
```

And I can view it as a pandas dataframe:
[image]

Is there a way to write this artifact as an MLTable artifact?
Or to register it as an mltable AzureML dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code block to get the file downloaded.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = ‘subscription'
resource_group = ‘your RG’
workspace_name = 'nov21'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='churn')
dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()

dataset.to_pandas_dataframe(on_error='null', out_of_range_datetime='null')

dataset.download('Churn', target_path='df.csv', overwrite=False, ignore_not_found=True)
```

This will download the file to the specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

In `mltable` version 1.0.0, a save method was introduced that will write out the MLTable file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/mltable/mltable.mltable.mltable?view=azure-ml-py#mltable-mltable-mltable-save

Artifacts should be stored in a folder. Therefore, you need to create a folder that stores the `dati_estra_test.csv`, so

```bash
# create directory
mkdir dati_estra_test

# move csv to directory
mv dati_estra_test.csv dati_estra_test
```

Next, create/save the MLTable file using the SDK:

```py
import mltable
import os

# change the working directory to the data directory
os.chdir("./dati_estra_test")

# define the path to relative to the MLTable
path = {
    'file': './dati_estra_test.csv'
}

# load from parquet files
tbl = mltable.from_delimited_files(paths=[path])

# show the first few records
new_tbl.show()

# save MLTable file in the data directory
new_tbl.save(".")
```

You can create a data asset using either the CLI (note the path should be pointing to the artifact folder):

```bash
az ml data create --name dati_estra_test --version 1 --type mltable --path ./dati_estra_test
```

Or the Python SDK:

```py
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

my_path = './dati_estra_test'

my_data = Data(
    path=my_path,
    type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE,
    name="dati_estra_test",
    version='1'
)

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
```

When the asset is created your artifact will automatically be uploaded to cloud storage (the default Azure ML Datastore).

It should be noted that it *isn't* a requirement to use Azure ML Tables (`mltable`) when your data is tabular in nature. You can use Azure ML File (`uri_file`) and Folder (`uri_folder`) types, and provide your own parsing logic to materialize the data into a Pandas or Spark data frame. In cases where you have a simple CSV file or Parquet folder, you'll probably find it easier to use Azure ML Files/Folders rather than Tables.

You'll find Azure ML Tables (`mltable`) to be much more useful when you're faced with the following scenarios:

- The schema of your data is complex and/or changes frequently.
- You only need a subset of data (for example: a sample of rows or files, specific columns, etc.).